# Align text of different sizes to bottom of list element

Tags: html, css

Given the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>One</span></li>
    <li><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><span>Three</span></li>
    <li><span>Four</span></li>
    <li><span>Five</span></li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;   
}

li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid red;      
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 height: 70px; /* height of largest element */
}

span {
 font-weight: bold;
 display: block; /* important, needs to be block */
}

li:nth-child(2) {
 font-size: 2em;   
}

li:nth-child(3) {
 font-size: 3em;   
}

li:nth-child(4) {
 font-size: 4em;   
}

li:nth-child(5) {
 font-size: 5em;   
}
```

Where each list item contains text of a different size.

I would like to align each `<span>` element to the bottom of it's parent `<li>` ensuring that the bottom borders also align.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/Xj5NA/) of this *not* working.

Need to support IE8 > upwards.

**Note: The items have to be floated**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `float:left` from li and add  `display:inline;  vertical-align:bottom;`

```
li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid red;      
 display:inline;  vertical-align:bottom;  
 margin-left: 10px;
 height: 70px; /* height of largest element */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xj5NA/12/)

Comment: The items have to be floated.

Comment: items are now aligned to the left if you see the demo

Comment: The issue is that the list items contain block elements, hence not being able to use `display: inline`. I've updated the original fiddle to make this clearer.

Comment: @Sowmya: I dont think they align with the bottom border. see the last li item, It jumps to top

Comment: @BenFoster when searching for some diff solution we need to fix the inner little faults with possible alternatives. Here we don't know what is your exact requirement to use block element. so either you should solve that by using this solution or try for new way.

Comment: Each element is actually a link that has a fixed width. I posted the simplest example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: then why dont you use a tag instead of span?

Comment: Both are inline elements so demonstrate the issue just as well.

Comment: @Sowmya I'm marking yours as the answer as it did *encourage* me to see if I could use display: inline. After working around a few issues (such as the li inline white-space problem) I got it working. See http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/Xj5NA/31/

Comment: @BenFoster Cool. This is what I do always, when I stuck with something I use to try in the other possible ways. Good luck!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:table` on the li element

and `display:table-cell` on the span element;

Also, by me the largest font-size works out to be 84px high.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DDMXm/1/)

Comment: 1. The text is not inline. 2. Is `table-cell` supported in IE8?

Comment: "Starting with Internet Explorer 8, the table display styles allow elements to closely parallel the visual layout of a table." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751%28v=VS.85%29.aspx